# Multiply Dropdown Field to Text Field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to create a calculator of sorts by using drop-down menus and quantities. How can I multiply the value from a drop-down to a text field, and have the result show up in another text field, using Javascript? This would apply to each line in the table.

HTML:

```
<table width="594" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col"><strong>Line Breakdown</strong></th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col"><strong>Qty</strong></th>
    <th width="90" scope="col">Unit Line Cost</th>
    <th width="90" scope="col">Total Line Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="122"><strong>Cabinets</strong></td>
    <td width="150"><select name="DDcabinets" id="DDcabinets">
      <option value="">Select an option …</option>
      <option value="100">Dura Supreme</option>
      <option value="110">Lenape Village</option>
      <option value="120">Wellborn Forest</option>
    </select></td>
    <td width="65"><input type="text" name="Qcabinets" id="Qcabinets" size="10" maxlength="5"/></td>
    <td width="41">ft.</td>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
        var select1 = document.getElementById('DDcabinets');
        var input1 = document.getElementById('Vcabinets');
        select1.onchange = function () {
            input1.value = select1.value;
        };
```

I added this Javascript, but it's not working - I'm guessing my Javascript math is a bit off (that and I'm just really unfamiliar with the coding.)

```
        var total1 = document.getElementById('Tcabinets');
        var qty1 = document.getElementsById('Qcabinets');
        qty1.onchange = function () {
            total1.value = select1.value * qty1.value;
        };
```

Also see http://jsbin.com/dodew/2/edit for the full script. [NOTE: You may have to adjust the size of the "Output" column to see the entire table of dropdowns and textfields.]

Comment: Are you really interested in using jQuery? It can be easily done without, just asking for some clarification. Also, you have a typo `var qty1 = document.getElementsById('Qcabinets');`, there's no 's' in `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so you're SUPER close, great job! The two things that you need to take note of are this.

```
// getElement(s)ById, no such thing! Change it to getElementById
var qty1 = document.getElementsById('Qcabinets');
```

The next thing, is the element values are stored as `string`, you need to convert them to integral values, I tend to do this with parseFloat, but parseInt is just as good of a choice.

Just change your multiplication to convert the strings to integrals, and you're fine!

```
total1.value = parseFloat(select1.value) * parseFloat(qty1.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
    $('#DDcabinets').change(function(){

           $('#Vcabinets').val($('#DDcabinets').val()) ;
        });

     $('#Qcabinets').change(function(){

            $('#Tcabinets').val( $('#Vcabinets').val()*             $('#Qcabinets').val());
        }); 

$('#DDcountertop').change(function(){

           $('#Vcountertop').val($('#DDcountertop').val()) ;
        });

     $('#Qcountertops').change(function(){

            $('#Tcountertops').val( $('#Vcountertop').val()*             $('#Qcountertops').val());
        });
```

Put this code inside document.ready

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CYLcY/47/)**